# Обновление RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview

В общем RecyclerView постоянно приходится свайпить сверху вниз. 
В моей задаче я сканирую шрихкоды и при новом штрихкоде в RecyclerView  появляется новый. Если он больше в кадре не появляется, по таймеру его удаляю

Демо видео для наглядности
https://vk.com/video92349898_456239362

Похожий вопрос уже подымался. Но рекомендации почему-то мне не помогли. Ну и сам код

Адаптер для RecyclerView

```
const val LIVE_TIME: Long = 7500

class SignalsBarcodeItemAdapter(private val connection: SignalsDataServiceConnection,
                                val countInterval: Long = 150

) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    val tempViews : MutableMap<Int, SuicideEntry> = ConcurrentHashMap()

    val timer = object : CountDownTimer(3600000 /*TODO*/, countInterval) {
        override fun onFinish() {
            tempViews.clear()
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }

        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {

            tempViews.forEach {
                it.value.timeRemaining -= countInterval

            }
            tempViews.values.removeAll {
                it.timeRemaining <= 0
            }
                    .let {
                        if (it) {
                            notifyDataSetChanged()
                            sendRefreshMessage()
                        }
                    }

        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup?, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        return SignalViewHolder.create(parent!!)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        connection.service ?: return 0
        return tempViews.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder?, position: Int) {
        val srv = connection.service ?: return

        if (holder !is SignalViewHolder) return

        val id = tempViews.keys.elementAt(position)

        srv.signals[id]?.let {
            holder.signalCard.name.text = it.name
            holder.signalCard.idSignal = id
        }
    }

    fun addNewBarcode(id: Int) {
        val result = tempViews[id]?.also {
            it.timeRemaining = LIVE_TIME
        }

        if (result == null) {
            tempViews.put(id , SuicideEntry(id))
            val index = tempViews.keys.indexOf(id)
            notifyItemChanged(index)
            sendRefreshMessage()
        }
    }

    private fun sendRefreshMessage(){
        EventBus.getDefault().post(
                EventMessage(BarcodeCaptureActivity.COMMAND_REFRESH_RECYCLERVIEW)
        )
    }

    data class SuicideEntry(val idSignal: Int) {
        var timeRemaining: Long = LIVE_TIME
    }


}

class EventMessage( val message: String)
```

Настраиваю в активити RecyclerView

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
....
        // Настройка динамического списка сигналов
        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.barcode_capture_recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
        mSignalsBarcodeItemAdapter = new SignalsBarcodeItemAdapter(this, 500);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mSignalsBarcodeItemAdapter);
...
```

А вот пробую делать (метод в активити) scrollToPosition

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void onMessageEvent(EventMessage event) {
    if (event.getMessage().equals(COMMAND_REFRESH_RECYCLERVIEW)) {
        mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(mSignalsBarcodeItemAdapter.getItemCount() - 1);
    }
}
```

Я пробовал и scrollToPosition(0). Не помогло.

Может вообще другой тип ViewGroup использовать?

Comment: вместо `scrollToPosition` использовать метод адаптера `notifydatasetchanged` не помогает?

Comment: Пробовал вызывать notifydatasetchanged везде где только можно - не помогало

Comment: Сейчас пробую удалять по команде notifyItemRemoved(index) а добавлять notifyItemInserted(index) .  попробую еще раз вместо scrollToPosition , что то мне кажется не поможет

Comment: Код на текущий вид адаптера https://github.com/LevWi/modbuster-blt/blob/Signals/app/src/main/java/com/lfom/modbuster/ui/barcode/SIgnalsBarcodeItemAdapter.kt

Comment: вместо scrollToPosition использовать метод адаптера notifydatasetchanged  не помогло - попробовал

Answer (score 0):

Помогло

```
mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
```

А Layout файл у меня был вот такой

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/topLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.lfom.modbuster.ui.camera.CameraSourcePreview
        android:id="@+id/preview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="50">

        <com.lfom.modbuster.ui.camera.GraphicOverlay
            android:id="@+id/graphicOverlay"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </com.lfom.modbuster.ui.camera.CameraSourcePreview>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="50">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/barcode_capture_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```